# Howto enable output from intel graphics card having nvidia drivers activated

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics

I want to know how to activate my second graphics card. The nvidia output is working well, but the second monitor (which is connected to the intel card) doesn't work.

I installed the intel drivers with the graphic installer. My configuration hasn't nothing to do with optimus chips, just a nvidia graphic card connected to a PCI port, and an  integrated intel graphic card into the mainboard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work in most cases. Each video card has a Bios in it, trying to take control of all video in the computer. You would need SLI or Crossfirecards to use two graphicscards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it works perfect with windows... any suggestion?